# Expressing total cost as a function of the length of a boxes base

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have a closed box with a square base and its to have a volume of 1500 cubic inches. If the material to make it costs $0.04$ per square inch, I want to express the total cost of the material for the box as a function of the length of its base.

Let $x$ be the length and width of the base of the box and y be the height. Then I have

$V = x^2y \Rightarrow 1500 = x^2y \Rightarrow y = \displaystyle\frac{1500}{x^2}$.

I know that surface area is $2x^2 + 4xy = 2x^2 + \displaystyle\frac{6000}{x}$ if you make the substitution for $y$. Am I done or do I need to do something with the $0.04$?

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is asking for the total cost, you are not done yet.
The material needed to make the box is $0.04$ per square inch, so for every unit of surface area you calculated, you need to multiply it by $0.04$.
Thus the answer should be $0.04(2x^2 + \frac{6000}{x})$